# Read data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to read the content of external JSON file and put in an array using javascript for further manipulations.

My JSON file is..

```
"Country":[
      {
         "Country_Name":"India",
         "Country_Details":[
            {
               "State_Name":"TamilNadu",
               "Capital":"Chennai",
               .................
               ................
            },
            {
               "State_Name":"Kerla",
               "Capital":"Trivandram",
               ................
               ................
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Country_Name":.......,
         "Country_Details":[
            {
              ...........
              .........
              .........
              .........
            }           
            {
              ........
              ........          
            }
          ]
         }    
       ]
      }
```

I have to use multi dimensional array (array inside array) i think.

I don't know to use push function on this array.

Suggest me something.Thanks in advance

Comment: not clear , be more specific

Comment: Which part are you having issues with? Reading in the file or mapping the data to an array? Please post the code you are having issue with so we can have a look why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having problem in mapping data to array only. I don't know how to map this to an array because this is like array inside array. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is JavaScript snippet for parsing your JSON based example file.

```js
function httpGet(theUrl) //function for loading in JSON file from gist
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var object = JSON.parse(httpGet("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/4d342372ed151964bbc03bbad1b4db65/raw/d843d183522f1b16eea1cfc9f3e36c9f22ff5e05/Country.json")); //object storing JavaScript object turned from JSON file (your example)

for (var i = 0;i<object.Country.length;i++) //for loop looping through array of objects stored in "var object"
{
  console.log(object.Country[i].Country_Name)
  for (var j = 0;j<object.Country[i].Country_Details.length;j++){
    console.log("Country Details - State: "+object.Country[i].Country_Details[j].State_Name)
    console.log("Country Details - Capital: "+object.Country[i].Country_Details[j].Capital)
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsoneditoronline.org/ this web site very supportive you to handle file data to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i want to map this full JSON to an array in javascript.